# Drawbacks of RF downconverting?

Tags: rf, frequency, signal-processing

I see a lot of RF systems use downconverting schemes in signal reception, like the LNBs for Ku-band TV signals. From what I read, digital downconverters do not harm the signal in the sense that no information is lost.

But this really makes me confused.

If downconverting is not that cost-expensive (Uhm, presumably. I have little knowledge in RF signal processing) and preserves the information, then why doesn't every RF systems in this world use one? There are tons of transceivers tuned to a specific range of frequencies like L/C/S/X/Ku/..., but wouldn't it be much simpler if we, say, have only one kind of transceiver and use an LNB to tune the incoming signal into the transceiver's frequency?

So I guess there are some kind of drawbacks, whether it's about cost or decoding problems, seeing people still make things like expensive SDRs. What drawbacks does downconverting have, if any?

Comment: Software defined radios are very recent. It would be wrong to ask why an older technology exists when a newer one also exists. Expense also matters a lot. AMD and Intel CPUs exist, so why don't we use them in our pocket calculators and household appliances?

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed to find an RF receive that doesn't use a "down converter" at some point.  In many cases these are also called IF mixer but the principle is exactly the same.  That includes SDRs.

Comment: You're the one who said "downconverting is not that cost-expensive".

Comment: @morimn Well they do make things a lot easier since they allow you to work at a lower frequency. Easy translates to cheap. To be honest, I have no idea how you would even do it without a downconverter but I am not a RF guy.

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If downconverting is not that cost-expensive (Uhm, presumably. I have little knowledge in RF signal processing) and preserves the information, then why doesn't every RF systems in this world use one?

There's many other things that can influence that choice. Sometimes your signal of interest is too low in frequency to be transmitted easily or filtered and you want to convert up... anyways:

> There are tons of transceivers tuned to a specific range of frequencies like L/C/S/X/Ku/..., but wouldn't it be much simpler if we, say, have only one kind of transceiver and use an LNB to tune the incoming signal into the transceiver's frequency?

Well, you'll find a lot of these systems are indeed using intermediate frequencies, so, basically, what you propose already happens (in the shape of superheterodyne architectures, or by zero-IF; some satellite transceivers even have IQ demodulators, only that their I and Q branches are themselves not actually low-pass signals, but IF signals, which get further filtered and then finally downconverted to baseband II, IQ, QI and QQ and reassembled into single signal digitally... don't think too much about that, it's an extreme example, but I added it to show that specific requirements can lead to *very* particular designs).

> So I guess there are some kind of drawbacks, whether it's about cost or decoding problems, seeing people still make things like expensive SDRs. What drawbacks does downconverting have, if any?

Don't know what you mean with "expensive SDRs": If you buy a 2€ integrated sub-GHz RF-transceiver-microcontroller, that's a superhet SDR. If you buy a < 1€ FM receiver IC that delivers digital audio: that's a superhet that does passband subsampling, with a high probability. You buy a Sigfox chip: ha! Mixture of direct synthesis and superhet, often with peculiar non-uniform ADCs.

If you buy a 3€ wifi chip, that's a quadrature downconversion SDR architecture with application-specific math accelerators. Same goes for every LTE phone, and twice for every cellular basestation of the last 20 years.

So, I think you're on the right track: for a lot of low-to-medium bandwidth, things are SDRs with down/upconverters. Only when the signal is already, for all practical means, already in baseband relative to what an affordable ADC can do will you do no further downconversion. (that's why there's a run for direct sampling in HF amateur radio: it's really no big deal to directly sample the 30 MHz bandwidth from 0 Hz to 30 MHz)